# Realm 3.5.0: Android: Correct token but on client side the method onChange() not call

Tags: android, realm

Realm 3.5.0, Android 4.3, Gradle 4.1

Task:

1. Create on Realm Object Server (ROS) my Realm with name "**myProjectRealm**"
2. Share "**myProjectRealm**" with all Android clients.
3. All Android clients must have ONLY read only rights for "**myProjectRealm**"

To do this I chose the approach using tokens (PermissionOffers).

Here server side code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        RegistryUtil.getInstance(this);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "init: ");
        Realm.init(this);
        loginAndConfig();
    }

    private void loginAndConfig() {
        SyncUser.Callback callback = new SyncUser.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
                Log.d(TAG, "loginAndConfig: onSuccess: Success_login");
                setRealmDefaultConfiguration(user);
                String token = RegistryUtil.getString(TOKEN);
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: loginAndConfig_token = " + token);
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: No token ---> create new token...");
                    createToken(user, new PermissionOffer(REALM_NAME_URL, true, false, false, null));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
                String errorMsg;
                switch (error.getErrorCode()) {
                    case UNKNOWN_ACCOUNT:
                        errorMsg = "Account does not exists.";
                        break;
                    case INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
                        errorMsg = "User name and password does not match";
                        break;
                    default:
                        errorMsg = error.toString();
                }
            }
        };
        SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(
                BuildConfig.USER_NAME, BuildConfig.PASSWORD, false);
        SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCredentials, AUTH_URL, callback);
    }

    private void setRealmDefaultConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser) {
        SyncConfiguration syncConfig = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, REALM_NAME_URL).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(syncConfig);
    }

    private void createToken(SyncUser syncUser, final PermissionOffer permissionOffer) {
        Log.d(TAG, "createToken:");
        Realm managementRealm = syncUser.getManagementRealm();
        managementRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.insert(permissionOffer);
                Log.d(TAG, "createToken: execute: Success realm_insert() NEW permissionOffer:\n"
                        + "\npermissionOffer.getCreatedAt() = " + permissionOffer.getCreatedAt()
                        + "\npermissionOffer.getId() = " + permissionOffer.getId()
                        + "\npermissionOffer.getRealmUrl() = " + permissionOffer.getRealmUrl()
                        + "\n\n"
                );
                RegistryUtil.setString(OFFER_ID, permissionOffer.getId());
            }
        });
        Log.d(TAG, "createToken: Wait for server to handle the offer");
        RealmResults<PermissionOffer> permissionOfferRealmResults = managementRealm
                .where(PermissionOffer.class)
                .equalTo("statusCode", 0)
                .findAll();

        permissionOfferRealmResults.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<PermissionOffer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(final RealmResults<PermissionOffer> offers) {
                Log.d(TAG, "createToken: addChangeListener: onChange: offers_size = " + offers.size());
                for (int index = 0; index < offers.size(); index++) {
                    PermissionOffer currentOffer = offers.get(index);
                    String currentOfferId = currentOffer.getId();
                    String realmUrl = currentOffer.getRealmUrl();
                    String realmName = realmUrl.substring(realmUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).trim();
                    String token = currentOffer.getToken(); // must be send to client
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChange: Iterate all permission offers!"
                            + "\nSummary report:\n"
                            + "OFFER: createdAt = " + currentOffer.getCreatedAt()
                            + ",id = " + currentOfferId
                            + ",r = " + currentOffer.isMayRead()
                            + ",w = " + currentOffer.isMayWrite()
                            + ",statusCode = " + currentOffer.getStatusCode()
                            + ",realmName = " + realmName
                            + " ---> TOKEN = " + token);
                    String findOfferId = RegistryUtil.getString(OFFER_ID);
                    if (currentOfferId.equals(findOfferId)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onChange: This_is_my_offer ---> set token");
                        RegistryUtil.setString(TOKEN, token);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Describe steps on Server side:

1. Created "**myProjectRealm**" on ROS
2. Success connected to ROS with admin user
3. The name of my custom Realm is "**myProjectRealm**". In this realm I has one table with some records.
4. After success login I create `SyncConfiguration` and set it as `setDefaultConfiguration`. See method `setRealmDefaultConfiguration`()

So now on server side I need to get new token.
My steps (method `createToken()`):

1. Get `getManagementRealm()`
2. Create new permission offer with read only rights : `new PermissionOffer(REALM_NAME_URL, true, false, false, null)`
3. Success inserted this new permission offer to Realm.

Logcat snippet:

```
 createToken: execute: Success realm_insert() NEW permissionOffer:

 permissionOffer.getCreatedAt() = Sun Sep 03 16:12:56 EEST 2017
 permissionOffer.getId() = c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666
 permissionOffer.getRealmUrl() = realm://myip:9181/~/myProjectRealm
```

4. Wait for server to handle this new offer (**c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666)** by the next filter:

   RealmResults permissionOfferRealmResults = managementRealm.where(PermissionOffer.class).equalTo("statusCode", 0).findAll();

5.After server handle new offer (method `onChange()`) I print ALL offers

Logcat snippet:

```
...
 createToken: addChangeListener: onChange: offers_size = 10
 onChange: Iterate all permission offers!

... 
 OFFER: createdAt = Sun Sep 03 15:48:37 EEST 2017,id = 47c71451-0505-499f-99e3-d5ad1ef0f40f,r = true,w = false,statusCode = 0,realmName = myRealm ---> TOKEN = fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:47c71451-0505-499f-99e3-d5ad1ef0f40f
 OFFER: createdAt = Sun Sep 03 15:49:42 EEST 2017,id = 47e3a781-b103-4c68-ad9a-3bdcc34780fa,r = true,w = false,statusCode = 0,realmName = myRealm ---> TOKEN = fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:47e3a781-b103-4c68-ad9a-3bdcc34780fa
 OFFER: createdAt = Sun Sep 03 16:12:56 EEST 2017,id = c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666,r = true,w = false,statusCode = 0,realmName = myProjectRealm ---> TOKEN = fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666
 onChange: This_is_my_offer ---> set token
...
```

As you can see my offer is the last (**c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666**)

6. After server success handle my offer then I get token = **fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666**

In logcat will be :

```
onChange: This_is_my_offer ---> set token
```

Now I send this new token (**fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666)** to all Android clients. OK!

---

Here client code:

```
public class MainApp extends MultiDexApplication {

 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initRealm();
    }


    private void initRealm() {
           Realm.init(this);
           String syncUserAsJson = RegistryUtil.getString(SYNC_USER);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "initRealm: syncUserAsJson:\n" + syncUserAsJson + "\n\n");
        if (syncUserAsJson != null) {
            String syncUserJson = RegistryUtil.getString(SYNC_USER);
            SyncUser syncUser = SyncUser.fromJson(syncUserJson);
            initRealmConfigs(syncUser);
        } else {
            loginToRealm(BuildConfig.USER_NAME, BuildConfig.PASSWORD);
        }
    }

    private void loginToRealm(final String userName, String password) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "loginToRealm: userName = " + userName);

        // callback of SyncUser.loginAsync()
        SyncUser.Callback callback = new SyncUser.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SyncUser user) {
                SyncUser syncUser = user;
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "loginToRealm: new Callback: onSuccess: >>>>>>>> Success login:\n"
                            + "\nuser_name = " + userName
                            + "\n- syncUser = " + syncUser
                            + "\n- ---> initRealmConfigs()"
                            + "\n\n");
                RegistryUtil.setString(SYNC_USER, syncUser.toJson());
                initRealmConfigs(syncUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ObjectServerError error) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.e(TAG, "loginToRealm: onError: ", error);
                String errorMsg;
                switch (error.getErrorCode()) {
                    case UNKNOWN_ACCOUNT:
                        errorMsg = "Account does not exists.";
                        break;
                    case INVALID_CREDENTIALS:
                        errorMsg = "User name and password does not match";
                        break;
                    default:
                        errorMsg = error.toString();
                }
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.w(TAG, "loginToRealm: onError: result errorMsg = " + errorMsg);
            }
        };

        SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(userName, password, false);
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "loginToRealm: ---> Try_to_login by: " + userName + " to address: " + AUTH_URL + " ...");

        SyncUser.loginAsync(syncCredentials, AUTH_URL, callback);
    }

    private void initRealmConfigs(final SyncUser currentSyncUser) {
        Log.d(TAG, "initRealmConfigs: currentSyncUser:\n" + currentSyncUser + "\n\n");
        String tokenFromServer = "fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666";
        RealmService realmServiceOrganization = new RealmService(currentSyncUser, tokenFromServer);
        realmServiceOrganization.setRealmServiceCallBack(new RealmService.RealmServiceCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String newRealmURL) {
                Log.d(TAG, "\n\ninitRealmConfigs: RealmServiceCallBack: onSuccess: Success get new realmURL:"
                        + "\nnewRealmURL = " + newRealmURL
                        + "\n\n"
                );
                Log.d(TAG, "initRealmConfigs: RealmServiceCallBack: onSuccess: ---> getSyncConfiguration() and loadOrganization()");
                syncConfiguration = getSyncConfiguration(currentSyncUser, newRealmURL);
                Log.d(TAG, "initRealmConfigs: RealmServiceCallBack: onSuccess: Success created syncConfigurationSG:\n"
                        + syncConfiguration + "\n"
                        + "\n ---> loadOrganization()\n\n"
                );
            }
        });

    }


    private SyncConfiguration getSyncConfiguration(SyncUser syncUser, String realmURL) {
        SyncConfiguration syncConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(syncUser, realmURL)
                // if use "waitForInitialRemoteData()" then call Realm.getInstanceAsync()
                // or create new thread and call Realm.getDefaultInstance()
                .waitForInitialRemoteData()
                .build();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "getSyncConfiguration: syncUser = " + syncUser.getIdentity() + ",realmURL = " + realmURL);
        return syncConfiguration;
    }

}
```

My service to get Realm url:

```
public class RealmService {
    private RealmService.RealmServiceCallBack realmServiceCallBack;
    private Set<RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse>>> realmChangeListenersPermissionOfferResponse = new HashSet<>();

    private static final String TAG = RealmService.class.getName();

    public RealmService(SyncUser syncUser, String offerToken) {
        Log.d(TAG, "RealmService_offerToken = " + offerToken);
        createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS(syncUser, offerToken);
    }

    public void setRealmServiceCallBack(RealmServiceCallBack realmServiceCallBack) {
        this.realmServiceCallBack = realmServiceCallBack;
    }

    // Call only if no realmURL
    private void createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS(SyncUser syncUser, String offerToken) {
        final Realm managementRealm = syncUser.getManagementRealm();
        final PermissionOfferResponse newPermissionOfferResponse = new PermissionOfferResponse(offerToken);
        Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: Create newPermissionOfferResponse (id = "
                + newPermissionOfferResponse.getId() + ") from offerToken = " + newPermissionOfferResponse.getToken());

        managementRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.insert(newPermissionOfferResponse);
                Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: Success realm_insert():" +
                        "\nSync newPermissionOfferResponse with ROS..."
                        + "\nnewPermissionOfferResponse.getCreatedAt = " + newPermissionOfferResponse.getCreatedAt()
                        + "\nnewPermissionOfferResponse.id = " + newPermissionOfferResponse.getId()
                        + "\nnewPermissionOfferResponse.offerToken = " + newPermissionOfferResponse.getToken()
                );
            }
        });

        Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: Wait for server to handle the offer with id = " + newPermissionOfferResponse.getId());
        RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> realmResultPermissionOfferResponse = managementRealm.where(PermissionOfferResponse.class)
                .equalTo("statusCode", 0)
                .findAll();

        // Guarantees that "RealmChangeListener.onChange()" will call EVERY time when application start first time!
        class RealmChangeListenerImpl implements RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse>> {
            private RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> results;

            public RealmChangeListenerImpl(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> results) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: RealmChangeListenerImpl:");
                this.results = results;
                realmChangeListenersPermissionOfferResponse.add(this);
                // add listener for permissions change
                results.addChangeListener(this);
            }

            // Call when Realm permissions was changed ---> receive new realmURL and setRealmSyncConfiguration()
            @Override
            public void onChange(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> incomingPermissionOfferResponseList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChange: FIRE onChange()");
                int incomingPermissionOfferResponseListSize = incomingPermissionOfferResponseList.size();
                Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: RealmChangeListenerImpl: onChange:"
                        + "\nRealm PERMISSION_WAS_CHANGED, incomingPermissionOfferResponseList.size = "
                        + incomingPermissionOfferResponseListSize);
                realmChangeListenersPermissionOfferResponse.remove(this);
                if (incomingPermissionOfferResponseListSize > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: RealmChangeListenerImpl: onChange:"
                            + "\n---> RealmService.this.onChange()");
                    RealmService.this.onChange(incomingPermissionOfferResponseList);
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: RealmChangeListenerImpl: onChange:"
                            + "\n---> EXIT");
                }
            }
        }

        new RealmChangeListenerImpl(realmResultPermissionOfferResponse);
    }

    private void onChange(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> incomingPermissionOfferResponseList) {
        PermissionOfferResponse incomingPermissionOfferResponse = incomingPermissionOfferResponseList.first();
        String realmURL = incomingPermissionOfferResponse.getRealmUrl();
        Log.d(TAG, "onChange: SUCCESS_GET_realmURL = " + realmURL + " ---> RealmServiceCallBack.onSuccess()");
        realmServiceCallBack.onSuccess(realmURL);
    }

    public interface RealmServiceCallBack {
        void onSuccess(String realmURL);
    }
}
```

Describe steps on client side:

1. Set this token : fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666
2. Login to ROS by not admin user
3. After success login create new **permissionOfferResponse** by user and new token (**fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666)**

The new permissionOfferResponse= **e4a0da61-9a60-4734-8b9a-8a54d781e6c9**

Method:

```
createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS()
   newPermissionOfferResponse = new PermissionOfferResponse(offerToken);
```

and insert it to Realm by :

```
realm.insert(newPermissionOfferResponse);
```

4. Wait for server to handle the offer (id = **e4a0da61-9a60-4734-8b9a-8a54d781e6c9**)

Use the next filter for this:

```
RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> realmResultPermissionOfferResponse = managementRealm.where(PermissionOfferResponse.class)
                .equalTo("statusCode", 0)
                .findAll();
```

5. After server response the method `onChange(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> incomingPermissionOfferResponseList)` must be call. (**BUT IT NOT CALL**)
6. After that get **realmUrl** from PermissionOfferResponse.
7. And as result I use this **realmURL** to work with ROS.

Logcat snippet:

```
RealmService(13701): RealmService_offerToken = fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666
RealmService(13701): createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: Create newPermissionOfferResponse (id = e4a0da61-9a60-4734-8b9a-8a54d781e6c9) from offerToken = fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666

RealmService(13701): createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: Success realm_insert():
RealmService(13701): Sync newPermissionOfferResponse with ROS...

RealmService(13701): newPermissionOfferResponse.getCreatedAt = Sun Sep 03 17:58:07 EEST 2017
RealmService(13701): newPermissionOfferResponse.id = e4a0da61-9a60-4734-8b9a-8a54d781e6c9
RealmService(13701): newPermissionOfferResponse.offerToken = fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c:c5b66e73-07c3-4e3a-bc2b-d9a8486cd666
RealmService(13701): createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: Wait for server to handle the offer with id = e4a0da61-9a60-4734-8b9a-8a54d781e6c9
RealmService(13701): createPermissionOfferAndSyncWithROS: RealmChangeListenerImpl:
```

As you can see the method `onChange(RealmResults<PermissionOfferResponse> incomingPermissionOfferResponseList)` **IS NOT CALL**!!!

As result I can't get realmUrl.

Why metohd `onChange()` not call?

Comment: I was going to say "try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781810/realm-why-on-devices-emulators-method-realmchangelistener-onchange-not-call-e/45783323#45783323 " but you're already doing that. Hmm.... But you are not doing it for `permissionOfferRealmResults`

Comment: I use your method. But the problem is not in it. It's work fine. If I remove filter (stay only **.findAll()** ) the method `onChange()` sucess call. But **permissionOfferRealmResults** has no my **permissionOffer** with id = **e4a0da61-9a60-4734-8b9a-8a54d781e6c9**